# jquery stopPropagation() and sending "event"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**(jsbin)**](http://jsbin.com/imager/2/edit)

I created a table with a button inside.

[image]

The Table has `onclick` event and also the inside Button

But when Im pressing the button ,the event bubbles up to the table. ( and I get 2 alerts)

So I used  `ev.stopPropagation();`

And its working. But in order for it to work , I had to do :

in html :

```
<input type='button' onclick='doWork(event);'/>
```

in Js :

```
function doWork(ev)
{
  ev.stopPropagation();
  alert('button');
}
```

- Is this the correct way ?
- **Must** I send the event ?  I know that different browsers uses differently the `event` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another [way](http://jsbin.com/imager/10/):

```
<table onclick="doWork();" border=2 style="width:70px;">

<input type='button' onclick='alert("button");'/>

function doWork(ev)
{
  ev = ev || window.event;
  var target = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
  if(target.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'INPUT'){
    alert('table');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't require passing event object and we can access it using window.event. [Old IE versions have not supported e.stopPropagation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgfjsxd.php). So, for cross browser compatability reason, you should try this:

```
function doWork(e)
{
    var evt = e || window.event;

    if (evt.stopPropagation) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }

    alert('button');
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer. does the html element should send the event ? and if so , why would you check window.event ? youll have it in `e` ....

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with this, and yes, you need to parametrise the event so you can call stopPropagation() on it in your event handler.